# Rendering extension-less files with php creates 404 errors when accessing the directory index

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm trying to render all files in a directory as php files. These files don't have any extension. I do this by adding the following .htaccess file:

```
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
DirectoryIndex index index.php index.html
```

The problem is that I'm getting 404 errors when accessing the index file on a url. For instance http://foo.com/mydir/ will result in a 404 error (in the logs) and a "No input file specified" message in the browser.

If I remove the SetHandler line things work correctly for the index file but my other pages do not render as php.

PHP 5.2.11
Apache 2.2.14
Linux

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By specifying `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5` on all requests, you are preventing `mod_dir` from doing its job.

I think this would work:

```
DirectoryIndex index index.php index.html
<Files *>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Options -MultiViews`